# Why the average weight of rnn keeps climbing?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pybrain

I'm using Pybrain to train a recurrent neural network. However, the average of the weights keeps climbing and after several iterations the train and test accuracy become lower. Now the highest performance on train data is about 55% and on test data is about 50%.
I think maybe the rnn have some training problems because of its high weights. How can I solve it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to restrict the network parameters is to use a constrained error-functional which somehow penalizes the absolute magnitude of the parameters. Such is done in "weight decay" where you add to your sum-of-squares error the norm of the weights `||w||`. Usually this is the Euclidian norm, but sometimes also the 1-norm in which case it is called "Lasso". Note that weight decay is also called ridge regression or Tikhonov regularization.

In PyBrain, according to [this page](http://www.pybrain.org/docs/api/optimization/optimization.html#finite-difference-methods) in the documentation, there is available a Lasso-version of weight decay, which can be parametrized by the parameter `wDecay`.